# php how to implode two dimensional array as arguments of array_intersect

Tags: php, laravel, array-intersect

I have an array of arrays like below

```
$array = [
  0 => [10, 20, 50],
  1 => [20, 30, 50],
  2 => [10, 20, 60],
]
```

and I want to give them as arguments of array_intersect like below

```
array_intersct($array[0], $array[1], $array[2])
```

but this is not dynamic do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php) like this

`$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$array);`

Answer (score 0):

Another variant would be to use the "splat" operator in PHP.

`array_intersct(...$array);`

It would be more cleared than using `call_user_func_array()` soltion provided above.